# git log --pretty to file with error

Tags: git, git-log

I do it:

```
git log --all --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %an%C(reset)%C(bold yellow)%d%C(reset) - %C(bold green)(%ad)%C(reset) %C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(bold white)'
```

Right result:

```
2c6f8b9 - Matheus - (Thu Sep 20 14:06:51 2012) ++ import clientes, ++ now send email ok! 
102c911 - LIVE - (Thu Sep 20 13:25:24 2012) ++ db 
93bf163 - Matheus - (Wed Sep 19 17:31:18 2012) ++ import clientes 
8539cf4 - Matheus - (Wed Sep 19 16:41:56 2012) ++ import clientes, ++ now with defaultBilling and defaultShipping 
843509a - Matheus - (Wed Sep 19 16:36:19 2012) ++ import clientes, ++ now with defaultBilling and defaultShipping 
b8de06d - Matheus - (Wed Sep 19 15:48:05 2012) ++ import clients
```

To my a file:

```
git log --all --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %an%C(reset)%C(bold yellow)%d%C(reset) - %C(bold green)(%ad)%C(reset) %C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(bold white)' > file
```

Wrong result when a save in file output:

```
[1;34ma36b984[m - LIVE[m[1;33m[m - [1;32m(Thu Sep 20 16:16:57 2012 -0300)[m [37m++ import clientes, ok!![m [1;37m
[1;34m1794d80[m - Matheus[m[1;33m[m - [1;32m(Thu Sep 20 15:31:28 2012 -0300)[m [37mMerge remote-tracking branch 'live/master' into import-clientes[m [1;37m
[1;34me8a1735[m - LIVE[m[1;33m[m - [1;32m(Thu Sep 20 15:23:00 2012 -0300)[m [37m++ db[m [1;37m
[1;34m7c838ef[m - Matheus[m[1;33m[m - [1;32m(Thu Sep 20 15:00:52 2012 -0300)[m [37m++ import-clientes, external file[m [1;37m
[1;34m2c6f8b9[m - Matheus[m[1;33m[m - [1;32m(Thu Sep 20 14:06:51 2012 -0300)[m [37m++ import clientes, ++ now send email ok![m [1;37m
[1;34m102c911[m - LIVE[m[1;33m[m - [1;32m(Thu Sep 20 13:25:24 2012 -0300)[m [37m++ db[m [1;37m
[1;34m93bf163[m - Matheus[m[1;33m[m - [1;32m(Wed Sep 19 17:31:18 2012 -0300)[m [37m++ import clientes[m [1;37m
```

I try without pretty format, work perfectly.
Later I try with pretty format, don't work!

How i can save this in a file, with a pretty format?

Thanks.

Comment: You have explicit color sequences in your pretty format. Do you want them not to be in your saved file as they apparently are?

Answer (score 0):

The output stored in your file is exactly what you've asked git for.

The first line, `[1;34ma36b984[m`, Maps to the color code to output blue in your shell (`[1;43m`), then your short commit hash (`a36b984`), then a color reset.

If you want the file to be readable on its own, omit the color codes. Alternatively, cat the file, and your shell should colorize the output.

Comment: `\e[1;34m` sets the color; `\e[m` should reset it. `a36b984` is just a commit id.